# WINAPI BM_SETIMAGE C++ что не так?

Tags: c++, winapi

Вот код:

```
HWND hButton;
HBITMAP hBitmap1;
```

...

```
    case WM_CREATE:
{
    /*
    HBITMAP hBMP = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"icon0.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0,
        LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"124", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW, 10, 4, 50, 54, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    HWND hButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"12", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_ICON,
    100, 10, 40, 40, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    //SendMessage(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hBMP);
    SendMessage(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap1);
    */
    HINSTANCE       hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"111", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_TEXT | BS_BOTTOM, 10, 10, 40, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)4000, hInstance, 0);
    /** /
    // use an icon
    HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME));
    SendMessage(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hIcon);
    /**/
    // or use a bitmap
    SendMessage(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap1);

    break;
}
```

Результат: кнопка с "111". Где иконка? 
В hBitmap1 изображение 20 на 20 пикселей.

Comment: Не особо специалист в этом, но не в том ли дело, что стиль кнопки задан как `BS_TEXT`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761822(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: МСДН говорит должно быть и иконка и текст.
Убрать или заменить на BS_ICON не даёт результата. BS_ICON даёт исчезновение текста.

Comment: "МСДН говорит должно быть и иконка и текст" -- это древний баг компонента BUTTON. Его обнаружили уже после того, как на свет появилась куча приложений, использующих этот компонент. Поэтому, чтобы не нарушить работу уже созданных приложений, было принято решение ничего не менять этом компоненте. Т.е. одновременно иконку и текст BUTTON показать не может. Хотя в сети есть авторы, которые утверждают, что у них это работает. Я думаю, это работает только с каким-то определенным манифестом (в XP, возможно - тоже работает, с его тормознутыми стилями).

Answer (score 3):

```
hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"111", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_TEXT | BS_BOTTOM, 10, 10, 40, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)4000, hInstance, 0);
```

Надо заменить на:

```
hButton = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Button", L"111", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP | BS_BOTTOM, 10, 10, 40, 40, hWnd, (HMENU)4000, hInstance, 0);
```

Comment: @Sv__t Я не могу оставлять комментарии.